# UnrealEngine4:how can I calculate the new vector after rotate and translate a distance from source vector

Tags: c++, math, vector, rotation, unreal-engine4

in UE4, how can I calculate the new vector after rotate and translate a distance  from source vector.

I rotate CameraComponent with Rotator(R1) from Vector(V2) and Rotator(R2) , then move forward for a length(L1) in this direction(R1), how can I calculate the new vector(V1) base on R1,L1,V2,R2? use c++ code is better,Thx~

Comment: I am unable to understand what you want to do. Do you want to know how to rotate something around an axis vector using C++ code? Do you want to know what the vector you end up with after the transformations? Maybe drawing what you want would be helpful.

Comment: Hi, @Noobs DeSroobs. I have resolve this problem, Thx all the same!

Answer (score 1):

yes, I want to know what the vector you end up with after the transformations. now I had resolve this problem.

I describe this problem again:

at beginning, CameraComponent is at **C point**, **Point A** is position of My Character, then rotates camera to **θ angle**(Rotator A) , then move **L** distance in direction of **θ angle** to **B point**, I want to calculate the vector and rotation of **B point**.

my solution code is like this:

```
Vector vC = ...;
Rotator rA = ...;
float L = ...;
Vector vB = vC + rA.Vector() * L;

//final transform of B point
vB.X *= -1;
rA *= -1;
```

[image: C point]